# Angular 2 changing class with ngClass

Tags: css, angular

In html I want to change the css of a span. To do this I use the ngClass function of Angular 2 by applying the following setup:

**app.components.ts**

```
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass } from "angular2/common";

export class AppComponent {
public isOn = true;
public toggle(newState) {
    console.log("newState: "+newState);
      this.isOn = newState;
    };
}
```

**In my html fileI have**

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign': isOn}" (click)="toggle(!isOn)"></span><span> Child</span>
```

When I load my webpage the icon looks correct (minus sign). However, the chrome inspector show the following css:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>
```

And after I click the span no icon is shown at all and the chrom inspector shows the following css:

```
<span class="glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
```

The issue here is that it should display the plus icon, but instead it shows no icon at all. My quess is that the above code does not replace the existing, but just adds another class and as a result the icon is not replaced, but no icon is shown at all? How can I replace the class of the span so that the plus icon is shown?

Comment: What would be the problem?

Comment: Eric, please see update above

Comment: Read this [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5763#issuecomment-166114033) it will clarify how ngClass work.

Comment: Thanks Eric. That helps. I also tried the above code with an "active" class (with a blue background) and a "disabled" class (with a background) and this works as expected. It looks likes the usage of the two bootstrap classes (glyphicon & glyphicon-plus/minus-sign) is not working well if a class is added

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, my suggestion would be to include `glyphicon-plus-sign` in your ngClass directive under an `!isOn` condition.

If you have a `-` in your class name you must use `<className>` with `ngClass`. Additionally, if you are using more than one class you can simply separate via commas.

Comment: What do you mean by "you must use `<className>` with `ngClass`? Can you post an example?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sure, for example I have classes item-focused and disabled. I must use single quotes around the class which has the dash.                                                                       `<div class="vg-list-group-item" (click)="select(listItem)" [ngClass]="{'item-focused': listItem.focused, disabled: listItem.disabled}">
  <div class="vg-content-holder">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>`